# How to catch a specific linux system return

Tags: c, linux, file, return

I recently started to use linux, so I have little knowledge about it. At least I know that every thing in linux is a file.

I would like to know how to catch a specific linux system return, for example if I choose install ruby (sudo apt-get -y install ruby), how can I know it was installed successfully?

```
char buffer[1024];
char *buf = malloc(4096);

char *pl;
FILE *fp;

if (strcmp(cmd, "ruby") == 0)
{
        fp = popen("sudo apt-get -y install ruby", "r");
}

if (fp == NULL)
{
        printf("Failed to load file\n");
        exit(0);
}

while ((pl = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) != NULL)
{
        strcat(buf, buffer);
}

strcat(buf, "\n");

pclose(fp);
```

Then I am using popen to read the file opened, but it contains the same that is shown in terminal and I just want a 'flag' like OK or FAIL.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: You might want the [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function instead?

Comment: why dont you just list the installed packages afterwards to find out if it is now installed?

Comment: You really didn't manage to read the popen() man page? Honestly?

Comment: Actually I didn't know about this page, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit code of apt-get will tell you if it succeeded or not (0 means success). pclose(fp) will return the exit code, so you can do:

```
if (pclose(fp) == 0) {
  // success
} else {
  // failure
}
```

You may notice, though, that now we're not actually reading from the pipe. There's not really any reason to have it. So like Joachim suggested, the system() function is probably a better fit for your case.

Comment: I really tried to use system function, but I noticed that after executing the command I should create a log then read from the pipe appeared to be the easier way.
As a matter of fact I am begginer in both C and Linux.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the exit status from the program being run. See: http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

```
The pclose() function waits for the associated process to terminate and returns the
exit status of the command as returned by wait4(2).
```

Every process provides an exit status (an integer, from 0 to 255) that indicates how/why the program
ended. 0 is typically used for a normal (successful) execution, this one is the one you should be 
looking for.

Try to see the manual page for apt-get or googling for the correct exit codes for apt-get.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to accept whatever answer was helpful to you (if any).